# Pandas dataframe: group across years

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

In Pandas, is there a groupby operation to group values across multiple years, when the rest of the timestamp is the same?

For example 12:00:00 01/01/2000, 12:00:00 01/01/2001 and 12:00:00 01/01/2002 would form a group, as would 15:00:00 01/01/2000, 15:00:00 01/01/2001 and 15:00:00 01/01/2002... etc.

I can sort of achieve this with:

`group = pd.groupby(timeseries, by=[timeseries.index.minute, timeseries.index.hour, timeseries.index.day, timeseries.index.month])`

but it is really ugly and not flexible to the input time format. What I really want is a way of excluding the year from the groupby, but including everything else.

Comment: Not sure what is ugly and not flexible here, could you elaborate in your question why isn't it working well enough?

Comment: By inflexible and ugly I was really referring to the fact that if the time series data resolution is smaller than minute, say second, it will not work as multiple data will be grouped. While unlikely in my usage, I want to try and cover as many potential situations as possible.

Obviously I could just include timeseries.index.second on the front (etc), but for smaller and smaller resolutions it gets a bit silly. I was hoping for a more elegant way to do it that is independent of the input data resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some constant `year` and then `groupby` by `index`:

```
timeseries.index = timeseries.index.map(lambda t: t.replace(year=2010))
print (timeseries)
group = timeseries.groupby(level=0).sum()
print (group)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract off a time-stamp for the start of each year to create a `TimedeltaIndex`. One way to do this in a vectorized way is converting to a different time-resolution `datetime64` type with NumPy, e.g.,

```
>>> idx = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=1000)

>>> idx
DatetimeIndex(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04',
               '2001-01-05', '2001-01-06', '2001-01-07', '2001-01-08',
               '2001-01-09', '2001-01-10',
               ...
               '2003-09-18', '2003-09-19', '2003-09-20', '2003-09-21',
               '2003-09-22', '2003-09-23', '2003-09-24', '2003-09-25',
               '2003-09-26', '2003-09-27'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1000, freq='D')

# note that pandas only handles datetime64[ns], so we convert back
# using pd.to_datetime

>>> deltas = idx - pd.to_datetime(idx.values.astype('datetime64[Y]'))

>>> deltas
TimedeltaIndex([  '0 days',   '1 days',   '2 days',   '3 days',   '4 days',
                  '5 days',   '6 days',   '7 days',   '8 days',   '9 days',
                ...
                '260 days', '261 days', '262 days', '263 days', '264 days',
                '265 days', '266 days', '267 days', '268 days', '269 days'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', length=1000, freq=None)

>>> group = pd.Series(np.arange(1000), idx).groupby(deltas)
```

One thing to watch out for is leap-years -- you will end up with a few dangling datetime differences of 365-366 days.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
t = pd.Series(['12:00:00 01/01/2000', '12:00:00 01/01/2001' ,'12:00:00 01/01/2002' ,'15:00:00 01/01/2000', '15:00:00 01/01/2001','15:00:00 01/01/2002'])
df = pd.DataFrame(t.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),
                               columns = ['Time','Date'])
df.groupby(['Time', 'Date']).required_function()
```

You get the data grouped on Time and then Date